# Textbox text "disappears" when it reaches end of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm using C# and WPF, and when I type in the textbox and it reaches the end (sometimes, it doesn't even reach the end), it "disappears" and the textbox is blank again.

Is it possible to make it behave like forms textbox (when you reach the end, for every new character, you would type only the leftmost character disappears)?

[image: WPF textbox]

[image: new line]

[image: desired]

Comment: Please share the code you're using to create the textbox.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have word wrapping turned on

Comment: Yes, @DaveM! Word wrapping was turned on, I turned it off and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out word wrapping was turned on, just need to turn it off.

```
MyTextBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
```